# How to covert a series into a numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy

I import a csv into a dataframe and got a  series like this:

```
In[1]:   A = df["data1"]
         B = df["data2"]
       type(A)
Out[1]:  pandas.core.series.Series
```

I make a pearson module like this

```py
def pearson(vector1, vector2):  
    n = len(vector1)  
    # simple sums  
    sum1 = sum(float(vector1[i]) for i in range(n))  
    sum2 = sum(float(vector2[i]) for i in range(n))  
    # sum up the squares  
    sum1_pow = sum([pow(v, 2.0) for v in vector1])  
    sum2_pow = sum([pow(v, 2.0) for v in vector2])  
    # sum up the products  
    p_sum = sum([vector1[i] * vector2[i] for i in range(n)])  

    num = p_sum - (sum1*sum2/n)  
    den =((sum1_pow-pow(sum1, 2)/n) * (sum2_pow-pow(sum2, 2)/n)) ** 0.5 
    if den == 0:  
        return 0.0  
    return num/den
```

And I want to use as_matrix to convert the series to a numpy array and it return a method not a numpy array, How did I get a numpy array from 
Series?

```
from modulas import pearson1
import numpy as np

An = A.as_matrix
Bn = B.as_matrix

p = pearson(An, Bn)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: You have to call `as_matrix`.

Comment: Also, you can use a series as a numpy array in most places.

Comment: How to call as_matrix, Could you speak detail?

Comment: Add parentheses at the end, just like you would for any other method...

Comment: @MadPhysicist `as_matrix` is deprecated.

Comment: @Amadan. Sure, but that's not what I'm addressing in the comment, and I do offer a better alternative...

Comment: @MadPhysicist: I see what you were saying, apologies. "You have to _call_ `as_matrix`" (as opposed to not calling it). Still, better not use it at all.

Comment: @Amadan. Totally agree. You also shouldn't run a list comprehension to add up array elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to covert a series into a numpy array?

Use [`values`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.values.html#pandas.Series.values):

```
series = pd.Series([1, 2, 3], name="a")
series.values
# => array([1, 2, 3])
```

Comment: I used the .values series turn to  array  but myfunction has the 'module' object is not callable

Answer (score 0):

change the code to:

`An=A.as_matrix()` ... you have to call the method in order for it to perform its' function on the pandas series

as @Mad Physicist mentioned, you can use a pandas series in place of a np array most of the time anyways

you can also do

```
An = A.values
```

I believe as_matrix will be replaced by values in future version of pandas

Comment: I think it possible my series is too  large, It has 14400 long .And my function did not work return  TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Comment: .values should work..I've done it with millions of rows

Comment: btw your function works for me as is..maybe something weird happened in the vec definitions? delete vars and run it fresh..either that or there is something you arent showing us

Comment: But my function don't work is there a error in it ?

Comment: Is there I turn off my jupyter notebook and reopen it ?

Comment: I have to add my module name to my pearson function like this `pearson1.pearson(An, Bn)` to run it